# How to docker compose up a jenkins agent node with git installed

Tags: jenkins, docker-compose

I docker compose up my Jenkins Agent Node with

```
  jenkins_barcelona_node:
    image: jenkins/ssh-agent:jdk11
    privileged: true
    user: root
    group_add:
      - "998"
    depends_on:
      - jenkins  <-- Master Node
      - reverse-proxy
    container_name: barcelona
    restart: "always"
    hostname: barcelona
    networks:
      - akogare-net
    expose:
      - 22
    environment:
     - JENKINS_AGENT_SSH_PUBKEY=ssh-rsa......
    volumes:
     - barcelona-data:/var/barcelona_home
     - /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker
     - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

This results in a debian container running a Jenkins Slave Node and works as expected. But there is one thing I want to improve. For my pipeline I need git here. So I connect via SSH to this docker container and install git manually here with `apt-get install git-all`.

Is there a way to deploy a Jenkins Agent Node with git already installed? So I dont need to manually install it.

Answer (score 1):

use build directive instead of image, then use Dockerfile to customize your agent image